# How to detect if device has on screen system navbar (Like Galaxy Nexus) or hard button using phonegap build?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I would like to know if the device has a virtual or physical navigation buttons (at the bottom of the screen, <kbd>HOME</kbd><kbd>BACK</kbd>).

I know this question has been asked but for Cordova, but not for PhoneGap specifically.